# Recommended way to debug Xamarin.ios webview js from Visual Studio?

Tags: xamarin, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

With 3 levels of abstraction (VS->Mac, Mac->phone/simulator app, app->webview), I'm not sure where to start.

I have cross-plat Xamarin app with nothing more than a webview (in Xamarin.Forms) hosting an external website (I also created). The website & all hosted apps (Windows/Android) perform very well, except on ios-webview. (Safari on ios and phone work fine). However, on ios/hosted-app, a 3 second load takes 60+ seconds.

Hopefully without having to add specific console/debug messages, how do I go about seeing where (in javascript), the time is lost - or what the issue might be?

Thanks,

Comment: Apple supports using the desktop Safari browser (under the developer tools) in macOS to debug Safari, UIWebView and WKWebView  on iOS, so you can profile the network requests, get a javascript console, etc.... Either do this directly on your Mac (personally recommended) or enable remote desktop and use VLC to add a 4th level of abstraction ;-) As a side note, `WKWebView` is sooooooo much better then UIWebView in terms of performance (among other things) and unless you have a specific support requirement for olders versions of iOS, I would recommend using it instead....

Comment: Sushi-thanks... (1) what iOS versions don't support WKWebView, and (2) got reference/link to how I might use/implement a simple WKWebView into Xamarin (currently using forms, but can switch out for this one).

Comment: WKWebView was added a replacement to UIWebView in iOS 8.0, Xamarin originally used UIwebView as they support iOS6(?) and above.... but for any new development UIWebView should not be used (Apple's official note: `Starting in iOS 8.0 and OS X 10.10, use WKWebView to add web content to your app. Do not use UIWebView or WebView.`). Not sure about a public OSS Forms renderer for `WKWebView`, I have one but it is not open sourced, might just want to Google/Bing/Github search as I know others have worked on this...

Comment: You might want to send a few minutes and create an Xamarin.iOS app, add a `WKWebView` to it and load the "problem" website to see if the results are worthwhile in pursuing a `WKWebView`-based solution (personally in terms of Javascript speed, ui rendering speed, w3c compliance, etc... it will be, but test it yourself on your content....)